# Setting up LinuxMint/Win10 dual boot

Tags: linux-mint, windows, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I recently bought a new PC with a 1TB NVME drive and want to set-up a dual-boot system with Linux Mint and Win10. My old PC ran solely on Win10 from an SSD with an additional HDD for data storage. For my new Setup, I want a dual-boot on the NVME and use the SSD and HDD from my old system for datastorage, preferably in such a way that I can access them from both operating systems. This is what I did so far:

1. Created Linux Mint boot drive
2. Changed Boot order to boot from USB first
3. Installed Linux Mint on NVME partition from drive
4. Created Win10 boot drive
5. Tried to boot into Win10 boot drive to install Win10 to other Windows partition

Problem: I go directly into GRUB2 where the boot drive does not show up at all, only my Linux Mint partition and my old SSD (which I disconnected for the time being, same for the HDD). The bootstick works just fine on my laptop

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947409/is-there-a-way-to-boot-from-usb-through-grub-menu) already but I get an error after using the `chainloader +1` command `hd1 cannot get C/H/S values`

This is my booting order[image: UEFI]

This is Grub2[image: Grub2]

This is the NVME partition I want to install Win10 on [image: NVME]

Comment: In UEFI mode, Windows wants lots of partitions. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations Better to just have unallocated space and let Windows add its partitions. Be sure to boot all systems in UEFI boot mode as both Linux & Windows install in mode you boot installer. And you want UEFI/gpt.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: The usual dualboot install order is first windows (as it's most ignorant regarding other OSes around), then linux; maybe this helps.